# module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' when running any pip command

Tags: pip

I am encountering an error  `module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'` when running any pip command on ubuntu v20. A solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428181/module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check) is suggesting upgrading `pip3 install pyOpenSSL --upgrade` yet for my case this is not possible since running any pip command instantly fails with the above error. Is there a way to resolve this? Kindly assist

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1429674